# Как соединить 2 txt файла в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, текст

txt1:    Иванов

txt2:    Иван

Я хочу получить на выходе:

Иванов Иван

Я пытался по типу:

```
file = open("txtfile.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")

txt1 = open("txt1.txt", "r", encoding="utf8").readlines()

txt2 = open("txt2.txt", "r", encoding="utf8").readlines()

file.write(txt1,txt2)
```

Comment: Смотрели какие параметры принимает write и что у вас будет в txt1 и txt2? В write нужно строку или байты писать, а в txt1/txt2 будут списки из строк. Да и для вашей задачи не нужно всё это...

Comment: начните с изучения того, как вызывать метод write (какой синтаксис допустим?). А также посмотрите на методы строк, раз уж объединить строки пытаетесь. Как изучите и перепишете скрипт - возвращайтесь, если не заработает.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы считал из файлов байты и записал как байты, тогда не придется указывать кодировку

Пример:

```
with open("txtfile.txt", "wb") as file:
    with open("txt1.txt", "rb") as txt:
        file.write(txt.read())

    with open("txt2.txt", "rb") as txt:
        file.write(txt.read())
```

Если нужны какие-то разделители между содержимым файлов, то записывайте их как байты:

- Добавить пробел:

  ```
  file.write(b' ')
  ```
- Добавить перевод на новую строку:

  ```
  file.write(b'\n')
  ```

Comment: А если в тексте несколько слов 
Смирнов

Иванов

Кузнецов

 и во втором 
Аарон
Абрам
Аваз

Comment: @Опача, нужно сразу писать в вопросе об обработке данных в файлах, приводить примеры данных, ожидаемый результат. Какое ТЗ, такой и результат :)